# Empty Interface vs Attribute, what about generic constraints?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

I have a class, which uses an empty interface as a "marker interface", like this:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public interface IMessage
    {
        //nothing in common here...
    }
    public class MyMessage : IMessage
    { 
        public void SendMyMessage()
        {
           //Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

I read in some other posts, but also on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182128.aspx) that this should be avoided, and you should use custom attributes instead of this empty interface. So, I could refactor my code like this:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MessageAttribute : Attribute
    {
         //nothing in common here...
    }
    [MessageAttribute]
    public class MyMessage
    { 
        public void SendMyMessage()
        {
           //Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but the main question is:

When I have a generic method elsewhere in my program, for instance:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : IMessage
{
    //Return all IMessage things here
}
```

In the above function, I do need to add some generic type constraints on `T`, so only `IMessages` are allowed. 
How could I accomplish this when using a custom attribute instead of an empty interface?

And does this justify the use of an empty interface? Or should I use an empty abstract class `Message` (instead of interface `IMessage`, since `MyMessage` is actually a `Message`).

Very curious about what you think about this.

Comment: You are trying accomplish two things with same thing which might not be a good idea. If you need to restrict your generic parameter type then `IMessage` is not just a marker interface.

Comment: @Muctadir: What else is a *marker interface*, other than an interface without any members that just exists for the sole purpose of being detected on a type (e.g. by a generic constraint)?

Comment: @Muctadir Can you be more specific? I already thought it was not the best solution, so i decided to post this question, but your comment is not really helping me at the moment... (Although i do appreciate it ;-))

Comment: What the point of having marker interface, if it does not define any common behavior, e.g. `SendMessage` functionality?

Comment: If `IMessage` has no methods or parameters, what exactly is the `GetAll` method gonna do with it?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky SendMessage is just an example, it should not be interpreted as possible shared functionality. The point is that i need to have something to define my generic type constraint in the GetAll<T>()....

Comment: @dcastro It does nothing with IMessage, but just sets the constraint that i cannot call GetAll<StupidTypeWhichMakesNoSense>();

Comment: But why does it need a type parameter? Why not `GetAll` instead of `GetAll<T> where T:IMessage`? How is `IMessage` relevant to the method's logic? `IMessage` has no members, so what does the restriction buy you?

Comment: @dcastro: The presence of an attribute such as `[Serializable]` or `[DisplayNameAttribute]` might be relevant to the method's logic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I believe that, if that was the case, then he would have never considered using the `MessageAttribute` attribute - he would just mark the concrete class with the `Serializable` attribute instead.

Comment: @dcastro: Ok, and how could he restrict the generic parameter to require the `Serializable` attribute then?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Like others have stated, that can only be done at runtime. In my previous comment I said that I don't think that's what he's trying to do. But I haven't offered any solution yet - I'm still trying to figure why he needs this in the first place. From the information we've been given, I don't see any benefits in using a marker interface.

Comment: The only thing the marker interface is providing here is type checking but (as stated above) that check does not give you any guarantee at all that the method will complete without error. Interfaces are a contract. There should be a guarantee communicated by the interface.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, i need this because i could have several classes which are marked as a message, but do not share behaviour or functionality. But i do need a GetAll<T>() where T : IMessage function, it's in some sort of generic repository class where i just want to return a collection of objects of type IMessage, let's say MyMessage objects, or maybe SomeOtherMessage objects which are also implementing IMessage

Comment: @Jeroen1984 I would just not use generic constraints at all. If the repository contains no objects of type `T`, return an empty enumerable. Like Marc Gravell said, what's stopping me from creating a `class Sausages : IMessage`? There is no restriction from a business logic perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [C# currently does not offer any attribute-based generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d5x73970.aspx), you have little other choice than to go with the marker interface.

Interestingly, the [documentation page on CA1040](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182128.aspx) states the following exception to the rule:

> It is safe to suppress a warning from this rule when the interface is used to identify a set of types at compile time.

Identifying "a set of types at compile time" seems to be exactly what is needed when evaluating generic constraints, and I am wondering now whether the author of that doc page had exactly this in mind.

Comment: Thanks, i did not even read that exception. I will mark your answer as the accepted answer because this exception exactly descibes my situation and my needs to us this empty interface

Comment: I'm currently going through this same debate on a project, and I would agree with @MarcGravell.  A marker interface can provide a compile time constraint which can sound good on the surface, but it doesn't necessarily provide maintainable code.  Without any actual interface methods, you're forced to do type-checking/casting at runtime in order to use any of your IMessage instances.  If any new IMessage objects need to be added, you're forced to track down every usage of the IMessage to make sure you're handling the new type.

Comment: @Scott: "you're forced to do type-checking/casting at runtime in order to use any of your IMessage instances" - if the `IMessage` objects only serve as containers for arbitrary data that is going to be processed (e.g. serialized) with reflection, this is not quite true. "If any new IMessage objects need to be added, you're forced to track down every usage of the IMessage to make sure you're handling the new type." - this is not related to marker interfaces, but occurs in any situation where you consume a base interface, but want to work with members introduced by subtypes.

Answer (score 8):

> How could i accomplish this when using a custom attribute instead of an empty interface??? And does this justify the use of an empty interface?

You can't - at least, not at compile-time. You could of course check for an attribute at run-time.

> Or should i use an empty abstract class Message

Base-classes are more restrictive than interfaces; personally I would impose the least overhead necessary. But I wonder whether even the artificial interface (which gives you nothing) is itself just overhead, and another option would be simply: *don't place any such demands*. Making people add an interface just so a method compiles doesn't give you an awful lot more than just having a generic method without a constraint in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can i prohibit that one can not call GetAll<StupidTypeWhichMakesNoSense>();

Comment: @Jeroen1984 Let them call with `StupidTypeWhichMakesNoSense`. You just throw `InvalidOperationException` or `NotSupportedException`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes it could be that simple, but i do prefer putting some constraints on it, so that it's more clear what the method accepts or does.

Comment: @Jeroen1984 having or not having that interface is not the thing that makes it "make sense"; something with that interface could equally not make sense, and something without it could be perfectly sensible. I don't know what the rules *are* for what "makes sense", but it has nothing whatsoever to do with this interface.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Getting a compiler error is always preferrable over a runtime error, isn't it? Otherwise, you could just type everything to `System.Object` and throw `InvalidOperationException` or `NotSupportedException` when you notice the object is of the wrong type.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper a compiler error here represents _nothing_. Make the error go away with an empty interface and it could still all go pop.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I agree with you but what will you do if language provide no such feature? You'll have to compromise in what language provides. And Gudsur has a valid point as well. Here compiler-error is stupid.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel there is no compromise required here; cover it with the test suite, job done

Comment: @Gusdor: As I said - then we could just as well type every parameter just to `System.Object` and do completely without any compile-time type checking. The fact that some exception could still occur at runtime isn't an argument against trying to catch as many errors at compile-time as possible.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the reason why you would choose to pass a string instead of an `Object` is because the method's logic depends on string-specific logic (e.g., string concatenation, StartsWith, etc). In this case, his method does _not_ depend on any IMessage-specfic logic - because there is _none_.

Comment: @dcastro: Simple example: Upon application startup, all types from all loaded assemblies that have been marked by their developers as serving some particular purpose are detected with reflection and are added to some list. Later on, a generic method `X` will only be able to process instances of types that are in that list. Clearly, the logic of `X` is dependent on the marking then (be it in the form of a custom attribute or a marker interface).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper it is only dependent because it artificially elects to be; it doesn't need anything from that interface / attribute, and it would work perfectly well without it

Comment: @MarcGravell: If it expects the respective type in the list, it would not work perfectly well without the marking as the type would be missing from the list in that case.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that really is in the domain of the design. What is 'intended' is not something a language can compensate for - hence bugs. My stance here is firmly in language territory - i.e. A marker interface is useless. It may serve function if the design states as much but arguably, that is bad design - a hack. I would love to know what `IMessage` instances need to provide for them to _work well_. Perhaps then we could suggest a better design.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you said "it is only dependent because it artificially elects to be; it doesn't need anything from that interface / attribute, and it would work perfectly well without it". I think this is the essence of my problem. But is it bad to have this artificially dependency??

Comment: @Jeroen1984: I did not say that, Marc Gravell said that.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ok i was just curious about how you thought about this

Comment: @Gusdor: Is the intention not always expressed by, say, identifiers? Languages can indeed provide some limited support for checking whether the intentions of the developers are being adhered to, and thus, to avoid bugs. For example, two interfaces with the same members are still not assignment-compatible, because they are two different types. They may look the same on a purely language-based level, but they were written with different intentions, they are consumed with different intentions and they will listed as implemented interfaces of classes with different intentions.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the recommendations in Microsoft's documentation say "generally favor X over Y", when it would be more helpful to note that there are cases where each will be correct and the other will be just plain wrong.

With regard to the choice between attributes, marker interfaces, and composite interfaces, the semantics of each will indicate when it is or is not appropriate.  The question of what semantics would be most desirable in a given situation may be a judgment call, but if one needs particular semantics the choice between attributes and interfaces is generally *not* a judgment call.

Any class which implements a public interface makes a promise to the whole world, on behalf of itself *and its descendants*, that any reference to an object of that class will be a reference to something that implements the interface.  In so doing, a class will make it impossible for any derived class to avoid making that same promise.  By contrast, an unsealed class with an attribute which promises some characteristic promises merely that the characteristic will apply to instances *of that class*.  There is no guarantee that it will apply to instances of derived-class instances which are identified by references of the base-class type.

If a wishes to specify that some characteristic will apply to all derived types, that characteristic should be expressed using some form of interface.  If one wishes to allow derived classes to individually decide whether to advertise a characteristic which the base class advertises, the characteristic should be expressed as an attribute.

Note that even if one decides to use an interface to express a characteristic, that doesn't imply one should use an empty marker interface.  If a characteristic will only be useful in conjunction with objects which also implement some other interface, a composite interface which inherits from one or more other interfaces may be much more useful than a marker interface which has to be combined with others in a generic constraint.  Among other things, if one had an empty marker interface e.g. `IIsImmutable` and one or more classes including `ImmutableList<T>` which implemented both `IIsImmutable` and e.g. `IEnumerable<T>`, it would be possible to pass a reference of any type which implements both `IIsImmutable` and `IEnumerable<T>` to a method whose parameter was constrained to `IIsImmutable` and `IEnumerable<T>` *but* given an `Object` whose type is unknown except that it is castable to both interface types, there is no type to which such an object could safely be cast which would satisfy both constraints.  If instead of using the marker interface, one had defined interface `IImmutableEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>`, then objects which implement `IEnumerable<T>` and want to advertise their immutability could be cast to `IImmutableEnumerable<T>`.

In some cases, it may be useful to have an interface `ISelf<out T> { T Value {get;}}` and then have marker interfaces accept a generic type parameter `T` and inherit from `ISelf<T>`.  Code which then needs an immutable implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` could take a parameter of type `IImmutable<IEnumerable<T>>`.  A reference to any class object which implements `ISelf<itsOwnType>` could be freely cast to any combination of marker interfaces that it implements.  The only difficulties with that approach would be that using a `thing` of type `IImmutable<IEnumerable<T>>` as an `IEnumerable<T>` would require using e.g. `thing.Value.GetEnumerator()`, and while it might be expected that `thing.Value` and `thing` should be the same object (implying that `thing.Value` should implement all the interfaces that `thing` does) nothing in the type system would enforce that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not wrong when the interface contains the SendMyMessage this method is required for this interface.

```
 namespace MyNameSpace
 {
    public interface IMessage
    {
       // If your architecture need this method and this method belong to this interface then why not ?!
       SendMyMessage();
    }

    public class MyMessage : IMessage
    { 
       public void SendMyMessage()
        {
          //Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

For example you can do that:

```
public class MessageRepository<T> where T : IMessage
{
  public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

or :

```
public class MessageRepository
  {
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : IMessage
    {
      throw new  NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but SendMessage is just an example, it should not be interpreted as possible shared functionality. The point is that i need to have something to define my generic type constraint in the GetAll<T>()...

Comment: You can create also an interface for the repository is this what you are looking for?